# Registering WPF Application with AutoPlay

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, com, autoplay

I want my application to be an option to run when a user enters a USB or a CD/DVD ROM to import the documents. So far I know this can be done via AutoPlay, but the more I read the more I'm concerned. I've found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh452731(v=win.10).aspx) (for Windows Runtime application, which I'm not using). It looks incredibly easy. However I can't guarantee the user will be on Windows 8 so I can't use that run time. So I've found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127452(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation from Microsoft, and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15626/Implement-an-Autoplay-Handler) example from code project.

I get lost when it gets to the shell extension in the code project example. Is this a necessary step? I thought I could just implement [IHWEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775492(v=vs.85).aspx) in my WPF application and be set. Is this not true?

Comment: Dave You can use process , Write code like , when any USB or CD/DVD ROM Insert  things insert . after you can start Import your document  with process You can also use Thread with process .